# How to share text in Instagram

Tags: android, android-intent, share, instagram

I need share text to instagram but I can't use android

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"MY TEXT");
```

nothing happen.please help me to do this

Comment: post intent code used for instagram

Answer (score 7):

Instagram have stopped accepting pre-populated capitions to increase the quality of content in the system. See this post.

http://developers.instagram.com/post/125972775561/removing-pre-filled-captions-from-mobile-sharing

Answer (score 3):

Generic code for sharing text with any social app :

**Step1 :** Get the package name of app you wanna share :

To get the package name use `adb logcat -s ActivityManager` this command in windows and run the app like for example you want package name for instagram so run above command and open instagram app you would get the package name in logs
Note : the adb command listed above is for windows . 
For ubntu you can use `adb logcat | grep "ActivityManager"`

**STEP 2 :** Once you got the package name of app below is generic code for sharing text .

```
 try {
                    Intent shareOnAppIntent = new Intent();
                    shareOnAppIntent .setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    shareOnAppIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getResources().getString(R.string.share_body));
                    shareOnAppIntent .setType("text/plain");
                    shareOnAppIntent .setPackage(PACKAGE_NAME_OF_APP);
                    startActivity(shareOnAppIntent );
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(ShareAppActivity.this, "APP is not installed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Instagram doesn't receives text from intent. it receives only `EXTRA_STREAM` object. you can share only images of format *jpeg, gif, png*. Since they are not providing any SDK you cant share in any other way.

Check Instagram developer documentation [here](https://instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/android-intents/)  they were clearly mentioning that the accepting Intent Parameter as `EXTRA_STREAM`

This is the code for sharing photo in Instagram

```java
String type = "image/*";
String filename = "/myPhoto.jpg";
String mediaPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + filename;

createInstagramIntent(type, mediaPath);

private void createInstagramIntent(String type, String mediaPath){

    // Create the new Intent using the 'Send' action.
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    // Set the MIME type
    share.setType(type);

    // Create the URI from the media
    File media = new File(mediaPath);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(media);

    // Add the URI to the Intent.
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

    // Broadcast the Intent.
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share to"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the intent code to share image and text in Instagram.

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"YOUR TEXT TO SHARE IN INSTAGRAM");
shareIntent.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
return shareIntent;
```